# playback video recording at UFT

Tags: qtp, video-recording, hp-uft

I'm using HP UFT 12.02 automation testing tool, and I'd like to know whether it is possible to record a video for the recorded script during the playback, along with screenshots for the verification points? If yes, would you please advice the steps?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Go to *tools ⇒ options*, select *GUI Testing* tab and *Screen Capture* item. Then check the *Save movie to results* checkbox and select when you want to save the movie.

[image: Screenshot]